# How to use the default Serilog console formatter explicitely

Tags: c#, logging, console, serilog, appsettings

For a microservices set-up (k8s) we've been using the following Serilog settings in the appsettings.json file:

```json
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Information",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
      }
    },
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithElasticApmCorrelationInfo" ],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console",
        "Args": {
          "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Elasticsearch.ElasticsearchJsonFormatter, Serilog.Formatting.Elasticsearch"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

The formatter that's being used, is specifically for our Elasticsearch instance and is really hard to interpret when running locally.
So I would like to use the default console formatter inside the appsettings.Development.json (or via environment variables).

How can I use the default console formatter locally?

I tried this:

```json
      {
        "Name": "Console",
        "Args": {
          "formatter": "Serilog.Sinks.SystemConsole.Output.OutputTemplateRenderer, Serilog.Sinks.Console"
        }
      }
```

AFAIK that's the default formatter. But when I try to run this, I get an exception:

```
A default constructor was not found on Serilog.Sinks.SystemConsole.Output.OutputTemplateRenderer.
   at Serilog.Settings.Configuration.StringArgumentValue.ConvertTo(Type toType, ResolutionContext resolutionContext)
   at Serilog.Settings.Configuration.ConfigurationReader.<>c__DisplayClass21_2.<CallConfigurationMethods>b__3(<>f__AnonymousType9`2 <>h__TransparentIdentifier0)
   at System.Linq.Utilities.<>c__DisplayClass2_0`3.<CombineSelectors>b__0(TSource x)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectListPartitionIterator`2.ToList()
   at Serilog.Settings.Configuration.ConfigurationReader.CallConfigurationMethods(ILookup`2 methods, IReadOnlyCollection`1 configurationMethods, Object receiver)
   at Serilog.Settings.Configuration.ConfigurationReader.Configure(LoggerConfiguration loggerConfiguration)
   at Serilog.Configuration.LoggerSettingsConfiguration.Settings(ILoggerSettings settings)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Edit

You can create different configurations, that will be loaded according to the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environmental variable.

- `appsettings.Development.json` where you set up the Console sink with the default formatter, so you can easily read the logs.
- `appsettings.Production.json` where you set the Elasticsearch formatter used in production.

To set environmental variable: edit `launchSettings.json`, otherwise right click on you project > Properties > Debug > Environment Variables, then set `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT = Development`.

This code, took from [official documentation](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration), loads the logger with the correct configuration.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production"}.json", true)
        .Build();

    var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
        .CreateLogger();

    logger.Information("Hello, world!");
}
```

## Original

To use the default formatter you can simply remove the whole Args block.

```json
      {
        "Name": "Console"
      }
```

It is possible to change the output template with:

```json
      {
        "Name": "Console",
        "Args": {
          "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss.fff} {Level:u3}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"
        }
      }
```

Take a look [here](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Formatting-Output) to understand how to customize the output template.

Instead, if you prefer to use a formatter that outputs in JSON:

```json
      {
        "Name": "Console",
        "Args": {
          "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Compact.CompactJsonFormatter, Serilog.Formatting.Compact"
        }
      }
```

Comment: I know, but I'm wondering how I can overwrite my appsettings using the appsettings.Development.json. Please read the question.

Comment: I've edited my answer to explain how to use different json configuration according to the launch settings

Comment: Yeah I know about appsettings.Production.json, but I didn't want to adjust all our microservices (+/- 30) to accomplish this.

Comment: The outputTemplate option worked perfectly for me. Thanks!